# Sharing an HTML link with an image

Tags: android, share

I know how to share normal text with an image but I want to share an html link with the image. If the user will share it and the second user will click on the link it will open a particular activity on the app.

What I've tried so far

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
String textToShare = "Check out <a href=\"www.activetoo.app.com\\launch\">" + service_provider.businessName + "</a>";
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

This just sends the text as a normal plain text.

Comment: Try to change your mime type  = shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

Comment: @IvanBarayev That doesn't include the image then.